# Download on a specific path (Base 64)

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, base64

I have that code:

```
$(function(){
    // This will act when the submit LINK is clicked
    $("#submitLink").click(function(event){
        var txtData = HERE I WANT TEHE USER CHOSE AN IMAGE;
        $(this).attr('download','sugguestedName.txt')
            .attr('href',"data:application/octet-stream;base64,"+Base64.encode(txtData));
    });
});
```

When I press a button, that code will be executed. When I run it, the file is downloaded to my download folder but I want to choose the path. I need the path of my javascript folder.

I also want what is saved in that path is an image chosen by the user as input

Thanks!!

Comment: You cannot choose destination path on user's behalf.How would you feel if some random website stuffed something up in your "private folder" ( or even better "systems" folder) while you were sure it was saving in "Downloads" folder

Comment: @Novice no!! I don't want that. I want when a user chooses an image of his computer, that image will be saved in my folder where I have located my javascript file

Comment: @LigaVirtualF1 So, basically -if I understand correctly- you want a file upload script, where a user will choose a file, and that file will be uploaded to your server?